# Breaking up a array formula that is too long using REPLACE

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to break up a array formula that is too long. Found an answer using REPLACE (thanks group!) but cannot get an a replacement using an already tested array formula. Replace solution works fine if I don't use an array formula as the replacement string. If  using an string representing an array formula, code does not error, but does not replace.

Basically, I am calculating a cost/lb where arrayTxt1 = cost & arrayTxt2 = pounds & arrayTxt1 / arrayTxt2 is cost/lb. Both array formulas work fine on their own. I have tried shortening the second array string w/o any luck.

```
arrayTxt1 = "=SUM(IF((master_PayDate>=R14C)*(master_PayDate<EDATE(R14C,1))*
(master_Supplier=""" & selValue & """)," & sumMetric1 & "))/1"

'this works
arrayTxt2 = "/CountA(master_Supplier)"

'no error but does not replace
arrayTxt2 = "/SUM(IF((master_PayDate>=R14C),master_TotalCost))"

'actual string I want to use
'arrayTxt2 = "SUM(IF((master_PayDate>=R14C)*(master_PayDate<EDATE(R14C,1))*
'(master_Supplier=""" & selValue & """)," & sumMetric2 & "))" 

Set selRng = .Cells(sumRow + 1, firstCol + 2)
With selRng
                 .FormulaArray = arrayTxt1
                 .Replace "/1", arrayTxt2, xlPart
End With
```

Comment: if you enter =SUM(IF((master_PayDate>=R14C),master_TotalCost)) as an array formula in the spreadsheet does it return a value? Or an error.

Comment: It errors. Excel suggested a fix & when I accept, it works. Funny thing, both formulas look exactly alike. Non-printing characters?

Comment: Probably a space where it shouldn't be. If you copy the correct formula back into your code does it now replace correctly?

Comment: Recorded a macro with the corrected formula & added that string as arrayTxt2 - still no error & no replacement

Comment: Just copied the string directly from the cell & pasted it into my code & it works! I'll try the whole string now

Comment: do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in the code?

Comment: "Cleansed" the whole string & it works fine now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Scott - just checked, no on error in this macro